# Spring authorization server and angular-auth-oidc-client logout not working

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I'm really having hard times trying to figure out how to manage logout from an angular app, which authenticates users with Spring Authorization Server.
Authentication process is managed at client side using angular-auth-oidc-client and it works without any issue; the problem is that angular-auth-oidc-client logoff() method doesn't work.
Inspecting Spring's log, it seems that the following workflow happens:

```
2023-03-13T12:31:44.443+01:00 DEBUG 22704 --- [io-9000-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing OPTIONS /oauth2/revoke
2023-03-13T12:31:44.445+01:00 DEBUG 22704 --- [nio-9000-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing POST /oauth2/revoke
2023-03-13T12:31:44.446+01:00 DEBUG 22704 --- [nio-9000-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2023-03-13T12:31:44.446+01:00 DEBUG 22704 --- [nio-9000-exec-1] o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy        : Redirecting to http://authorization:9000/login
2023-03-13T12:31:44.450+01:00 DEBUG 22704 --- [nio-9000-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing OPTIONS /login
2023-03-13T12:31:44.454+01:00 DEBUG 22704 --- [nio-9000-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /login
2023-03-13T12:31:44.459+01:00 DEBUG 22704 --- [nio-9000-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing POST /oauth2/revoke
```

So, it seems that the client-library hits the token revoke endpoint, but for somewhat reason, it complains that the whole logout process fails.
The very first strange thing I can see is that after the first hit on /oaut2/revoke endpoint, Spring requires a redirect to standard login page - I use Spring default login form to allow user enter its own credential; but another attempt to perform /oauth2/revoke
is performed immediately after.

This is my whole security configuration:

```
@Bean 
   @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
   public SecurityFilterChain authorizationServerSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
       OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.applyDefaultSecurity(http);
       http.getConfigurer(OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer.class).oidc(Customizer.withDefaults());
       http
           .exceptionHandling((exceptions) -> exceptions
               .authenticationEntryPoint(
                   new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/login"))

           );
       OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer authorizationServerConfigurer  = http.getConfigurer(OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer.class);
       authorizationServerConfigurer
               .tokenRevocationEndpoint(tokenRevocationEndpoint ->
                       tokenRevocationEndpoint
                               .revocationResponseHandler((request, response, authentication) -> log.info("Token Revocation Request received"))
               );
       setupCors(http);
       return http.build();
   }

   @Bean
   @Order(2)
   SecurityFilterChain apiSecurityFilter(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
       http.securityMatcher("/api/application/public/**")
               .authorizeHttpRequests()
               .requestMatchers("/api/application/public/**").permitAll();
       http.securityMatcher("/api/application/**")
               .authorizeHttpRequests()
                   .requestMatchers("/api/application/**").authenticated()
                   .and()
           .oauth2ResourceServer().jwt();
       setupCors(http);
       return http.build();
   }
   
   @Bean 
   @Order(3)
   public SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
       http
           .securityMatcher("/oauth2/**", "/login")
               .authorizeHttpRequests()
               .requestMatchers("/oauth2/**", "/login")
               .authenticated()
               .and()
           .formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults());
       setupCors(http);
       return http.build();
   }
```

Another strange issue is that I never get the log *Token Revocation Request received* printed, just like if logout configuration is ignored.
Any hints ?

Comment: It looks strange to me that the filter-chain without `securityMatcher` is the first in order (it should be the last one so that it acts as default for the route not matched by others).

Comment: Also, the last filter-chain (`defaultSecurityFilterChain`) looks quite like a client filter-chain (and neither an authorization-server not resource-server one). What are your dependencies exactly?

Comment: More or less is the very same configuration you can read in Spring's official how-to guides pages: [link](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/tree/main/samples/default-authorizationserver/src/main/java/sample/config).
Just merged shown configuration in a single one.

Comment: By the way, after hitting /oauth2/revoke endpoint, which should be the expected behaviour of the flow ?